# Regexp to catch string between first and second comma, where there's alphabetical character in number

Tags: regex, csv, sed

First, I must mention my native language is french, so I may make english mistake!

I try to use sed to catch and delete the lines where the second item in a CSV file contains other characters then numbers.

Here is an example of a OK line :

```
2323421,9781550431209,,2012-07-24 13:30:57,False,2012-07-01 00:00:00,False,118,,1,246501
```

A line that must be deleted :

```
1901461,3002CAN,,2010-09-29 13:46:59,True,,True,,,,
```

or

```
2977837,9782/76132396,,2015-04-27 10:14:47,True,2015-04-26 00:00:00,True,,,,
```

etc...

I'm not sure this is possible to be honest!

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/' file
```

Or (thanks to @ghoti):

```
awk -F, '$2 !~ /[^[:digit:]]/' file
```

to get only those line where 2nd column is an integer number.

Or using `sed` you can do:

```
sed -i.bak '/^[^,]*,[[:digit:]]*[^,[:digit:]]/d' file
```

Comment: For the awk solution, why not `awk -F, '$2 !~ /[^[:digit:]]/'` ? Wouldn't a search for a single character in the class be more performant than a regex anchored at start and end?

Comment: @ghoti: Yes agreef, that might be good condition to use (edited)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using `sed`

```
sed -e '/^[^,]*,[^,]*[^0-9,]/d'
```

A breakdown of the pattern:

`^` Start of line

`[^,]*,` Everything up to the first comma inclusive

`[^,]*` Everything which isn't a comma

`[^0-9,]` At least one character which isn't a number or comma

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

`perl -F, -lane 'print if $F[1] =~ /^\d+$/' file`

`-a` autosplit line to array `@F`, fields start with 0
`-F,` splits line using commas
print the line only if field 1 contain only digits:  `/^\d+$/`